# Allow Anonymous user to Subscribe while site under maintenance mode

Tags: maintenance-mode, notifications

The title says it all.
I have customized the Maintenance mode page, to Coming soon!!
how i want to enable the visitors of the website to Subscribe So they'll will be notified when the website is officially lunched.
how can i Achieve this, am developing the website in Drupal in 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you ask for is akin to asking "I've turned my TV off, how can I watch Channel [something] on it?". The answer is to turn it on. Maintenance mode basically turns Drupal off.

Answer (score 2):

Maintenance mode is not really for this.

I would recommend using a custom theme for "Coming soon".   That way you can have them come to a home page with information and sign up/register for the site.

When you're ready to put the real site up, change themes.

Comment: Agreed. The short answer is, "You can't", and if you want to, your misusing the maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your sie in permanent "maintenance mode". Instead use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to achieve the same goal.

All that's needed is some tuning of the "Custom rule" I suggested also as an answer to the question about "[How can I put a Drupal Commerce site in 'Shop Closed' mode, similar to Drupal's maintenance mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149005/how-can-i-put-a-drupal-commerce-site-in-shop-closed-mode-similar-to-drupals/165989#165989)".

In your case you'd probably want to block mostly every URL being visited, except the "User registration" page.

Answer (score -2):

I have prepared a step by step guide for allowing the anonymous user to subscribe for the node update.

Visit this link for a complete guide:
http://c.pachabhaiya.com/blog/2013/08/drupal-how-to-make-anonymous-user-subscription-on-a-particular-node-update/

- Possibility for the anonymous users to subscribe to particular node.
- Send email notifications automatically to the subscribed users when
  that particular node is updated.

Comment: The link is invalid